# chromebook crouton install raring with cli-extra, so no pdf view in emacs?

Tags: emacs24, chromebook

Total newbie questions, here. But I installed raring with cli-extra options. Then installed emacs24. I installed texlive. Now with C-c C-c command I can compile .tex documents in emacs. But I don't get a view of it.

My question is, is this because I never installed an X interface? Or is because I am accessing emacs through SecureShell in the ChromeOS?

Thanks so much, please correct any misunderstandings I have. Anyone have suggestions where I can look to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Without a desktop environment there isn't anything that will be able to display images (the pdf).

An example of this is when you have images like pngs in your .emacs.desktop and you open it in no window mode (-nw), emacs gives an error as linux terminals don't support images.

If you want this functionality I'd recommend either loading a desktop manager like xfce, or open the pdf in chrome os, and hopefully it will update automatically when the pdf is re-rendered, otherwise you should just be able to refresh to update it.